# Why firebase is not able to query data from collection in recycler view?

Tags: java, android, database, firebase, comments

I am able to get data in firebase collection but it does not query that data in recycler view. Recyclerview does not showing anything[image]

This is the comment_list class.

```
public class comment_list {
    public comment_list(String comments) {
        this.comments = comments;
    }

    public String getComments() {
        return comments;
    }

    public void setComments(String comments) {
        this.comments = comments;
    }

    String comments;
}
```

This is comment_adapter class

```
public class comment_adapter extends FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<comment_list, comment_adapter.comment_holder> {
  
    public comment_adapter(@NonNull FirestoreRecyclerOptions<comment_list> options) {
        super(options);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull comment_holder holder, int position, @NonNull comment_list model) {
        holder.commment_on_post.setText(model.getComments());
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public comment_holder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.comment_recycler_dsign, parent, false);
        return new comment_holder(v);
    }

    public class comment_holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
      TextView commment_on_post;
        public comment_holder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            commment_on_post = itemView.findViewById(R.id.commenttextview);
        }
    }
```

This is Comments class. In this I am able to get data in firebase collection but it is not query that data in recycler view.

```
public class Comments extends AppCompatActivity {
 ImageView profileimage;
 EditText addcommenttext;
 TextView postcommenttext;
    FirebaseFirestore db;
  
    RecyclerView comment_recycler_view;

   comment_adapter adaptercomment;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_comments);

        profileimage = findViewById(R.id.Addcommentprofileimage);
        addcommenttext = findViewById(R.id.addcommenttext);
        postcommenttext = findViewById(R.id.postcomment);
    
comment_recycler_view = findViewById(R.id.commentsrecycler);




        postcommenttext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (addcommenttext.equals("")) {
                    Toast.makeText(Comments.this, "Comment can't be empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    String commentText = addcommenttext.getText().toString();

                    CollectionReference commentref = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance() .collection("CommentDetails");
                    commentref.add(new comment_list(commentText));

         

                    
                    FirebaseFirestore fbfs = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
                    CollectionReference commentrefs = fbfs.collection("CommentDetails");
                    Query query = commentrefs;

                    FirestoreRecyclerOptions<comment_list> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<comment_list>()
                            .setQuery(query, comment_list.class)
                            .build();
                    adaptercomment = new comment_adapter(options);

                    comment_recycler_view.setHasFixedSize(true);
                    comment_recycler_view.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplication()));
                    comment_recycler_view.setAdapter(adaptercomment);
                    finish();
                    Toast.makeText(Comments.this, "Commented", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }


    });

}
```

Comment: Please post your database structure

Comment: The data in your database

Comment: your mean collection in cloud firestore?

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot. Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo i did please check

Comment: Does `model.getComments()` return something?

Comment: it return comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, let's reconfigure your *Comments* activity class. It would be recommended to initialise the recycle adapter in your `onCreate` method and not in the overridden `onClick` method. With the current set up, a new *comment_adapter* is initialised every time the onClick listener is triggered. It's best that we set-up only one. Here's how things look after the changes (I've added comments for clarity):

*NOTE: I have renamed classes, variables and methods to use java and android conventions for clarity. Learning these will help you a lot in being able to read others code and save you a lot of headaches with your own code.*

```
public class CommentsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    FirebaseFirestore db;
    CommentAdapter commentAdapter;

    ImageView profileImageView;
    EditText commentEditText;
    RecyclerView commentRecyclerView;
    Button addCommentButton; // Replaces the text view you are using

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        profileImageView = findViewById(R.id.add_comment_profile_image);
        commentEditText = findViewById(R.id.comment_edit_text);
        addCommentButton = findViewById(R.id.add_comment_button);
        commentRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.comments_recycle_view);

        // Enables firestore debugging which will help a lot when trying to troubleshoot
        FirebaseFirestore.setLoggingEnabled(true);

        // We are now setting up our query directly within the OnCreate method.
        db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        Query query = db.collection("CommentDetails").orderBy("timestamp").limit(50);

        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Comment> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Comment>()
                .setQuery(query, Comment.class)
                .build();

        // Setting up the recycle adapter in onCreate
        commentAdapter = new CommentAdapter(options);
        commentRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        commentRecyclerView.setAdapter(commentAdapter);

        // Set up your onClickListener just as before.
        addCommentButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // Note that the previous null check is unsuccessful. Previously, the object instance
                // was being checked, and not the contents of the edit text. This resolves that issue. (:
                if (commentEditText.toString().isEmpty()) {
                    Toast.makeText(CommentsActivity.this, "Comment can't be empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    String commentText = commentEditText.getText().toString();
                    CollectionReference commentColRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("CommentDetails");
                    commentColRef.add(new Comment(commentText));
                    Toast.makeText(CommentsActivity.this, "Commented", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        commentAdapter.startListening();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        commentAdapter.stopListening();
    }
}
```

You will notice the addition of two new methods: `onStart` and `onStop`. Within these methods we start and stop the query listeners attached to the `FirestoreRecyclerAdapter`. It will be really helpful to refer to the [FirebaseUI for Cloud Firestore read-me](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/firestore#using-the-firestorerecycleradapter).

It is important to note in the code above I also renamed your data model from *comment_list* to **Comment**. The reason for this, is that an instance of this class only stores the state of one comment. It does not store a list of comments. I think it might cause confusion when you are trying to debug your code. In the case of using FirebaseUI, the actual list of comments (the *comments list*) which is bound to your recycle view is built for you by the FirebaseUI code, in the form of an array of **Comment** class instances.

In order to understand clearly how this is done, it might be useful to spend a couple of hours implementing a simple recycle view and adapter that is not connected to Firestore. That way a greater understanding as to how FirebaseUI is doing things can be developed. There are docs on that [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview).

Finally - here is a replacement to the comment_list class:

```
public class Comment {

    String comment;
    @ServerTimestamp Date timestamp;

    // A zero argument constructor is required by firestore.
    public Comment() {
    }

    public Comment(String comment) {
        this.comment = comment;
    }

    public String getComment() {
        return comment;
    }

    public void setComment(String comment) {
        this.comment = comment;
    }

    public Date getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }

    public void setTimestamp(Date timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }
```

The only difference here is there is a zero-args (no argument) constructor, which is required by firestore.

A word to the wise - I haven't seen your view model item layout (`comment_recycler_dsign`), but just check that the root layout does not have a height of "match_parent". This is a common mistake. It is a good idea to check this first if you see only one recycle item being rendered.

Comment: It works thank you. Can you please tell me how can I order query like if I post comment then it appears on top then next appear on top?

Comment: A problem occurring that every comment shows in every post, not in a single post

Comment: @Harnoor Try adding a "timestamp" field into the Comment class. Every time a comment is made, post a timestamp along with it. Then edit your firebase query to `Query query = db.collection("chats").orderBy("timestamp").limit(50);`

Have a look at (https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/firestore#using-the-firestorerecycleradapter). The example implementation is perfect for what you are trying to do. (= Good luck!

Comment: Not working properly, comment posted not accurately means comment not posted according to the newest first appear

Comment: @Harnoor Here is a working implementation that you can refer too. (:
(https://github.com/michael-lundie/stackoverflow_temp) I've also updated the code in the above answer with the timestamp functionality.

Comment: Now it is the opposite,  newest comes in last not in first

Comment: @Harnoor You'll find what you need here: (https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data)

Answer (score 0):

Place a listener
fire base will automatically call once the upload is complete

```
 firestore.collection("").add(Any()).addOnCompleteListener { 
                    // do all your work here
 }
```

Comment: The OP, Harnoor, is using FirebaseUI and `FirestoreRecyclerAdapter`. In this case, listeners are handled via the adapter by calling it's  `startListening()` and `stopListening()` methods respectively. The above would of course be required in the case of using your own custom adapter implementation however.